# A question of a compact operator?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators, nonlinear-analysis

Show that $u \mapsto \int_{\Omega} \nabla u_0 \nabla u $ is a compact operator?

where $\Omega$ is a bounded subset of $R^n,$ $\Omega$ satisfies the codintion of the sobolev embedding theorem, and $u_0,u \in H_0^1 \left( \Omega \right).$

Could anyone help me to give a solution for the problem! Thank you!

Comment: It's not even bounded. How can it be compact? Are you sure $u $ is not in some Sobolev space?

Comment: sorry! $u_0, u \in H_0^1$

Comment: can you help me? tks

Comment: It's a bounded linear functional, so a compact operator.

Comment: I don't see why the operator is bounded? can you tell me about that?

Comment: Use Cauchy-Schwarz and the definition of the $H^1_0$ norm.

Comment: I cannot find out the theorem that a bounded linear functional is compact operator! You can tell me where I can see that ?

Comment: Well a bounded linear operator sends bounded sets to bounded sets, but bounded sets in a finite dimensional space are pre-compact.

Comment: yeah! thak you! I'm stupid

Comment: sorry but I cannot still see how to use cauchy - Schwarz?

$ \vert \int_{\Omega} \nabla u_0 \nabla u  \vert \leq \Vert \nabla u_0 \Vert _{H^1} \Vert \nabla u \Vert _{H^1}$
If I use the Poincare inequality then it is not useful!
so how to do that?

Comment: Use Hölder's inequality: $ \int_{\Omega} | \nabla u_0 \nabla u | \leq || \nabla u_0 ||_{L^2(\Omega)} || \nabla u ||_{L^2(\Omega)}$ and notice $||\nabla u||_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq ||u||_{H^1_0(\Omega)}$.